# Como ler uma lista de objetos serializados salvos em um arquivo em java?

Tags: java, arquivo, io

Estava querendo trabalhar com serialização em arquivos em java e li este tutorial sobre [como escrever o objeto no arquivo](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/?utm_source=mkyong&utm_medium=author&utm_campaign=related-post&utm_content=7) e este outro sobre o [como ler o objeto do arquivo](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-an-object-from-file-in-java/?utm_source=mkyong&utm_medium=author&utm_campaign=related-post&utm_content=3)

Então criei a seguinte classe que salva o objeto Adreess no arquivo "arquivo.ser":

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import wl.revisao.write.Address;

    public class WriteObject {

        public void serializeAddressJDK7(Address address) {

            try (ObjectOutputStream oos
                    = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("arquivo.ser",true))) {

                oos.writeObject(address);
                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

         public Address deserialzeAddressJDK7(String filename) {

            Address address = null;

            try (ObjectInputStream ois
                    = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) {

                address = (Address) ois.readObject();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return address;

        }
```

> //Metodo indicado pelo amigo Isac com a resposta abaixo

```
public List<Address> recuperarTodos() {
        List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>(); //lista de Address

        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("arquivo.res"))) {

            while (true) {
                Address address = new Address();

                address = (Address) ois.readObject(); //le outro objeto e adicionar à lista
                addresses.add(address); //le outro objeto e adicionar à lista
            }

        } catch (EOFException ex) {

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;

    }

}
```

Aqui esta a minha classe principal:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        WriteObject obj = new WriteObject();

        Address address = new Address();
        address.setStreet("Wall street");
        address.setCountry("United States Of America");

        Address address2 = new Address();
        address2.setStreet("Avenida Brasil");
        address2.setCountry("Brasil");

        obj.serializeAddressJDK7(address);
        obj.serializeAddressJDK7(address2);

//   obj.deserialzeAddressJDK7("arquivo.ser");
       System.out.println(obj.recuperarTodos());
    }
}
```

O outro metodo deserialzeAddressJDK7 devolve um objeto Address  lido do arquivo.

Ok tudo esta perfeito!!
O problema é quando eu salvo mais de um objeto no arquivo "arquivo.ser", pois 
o metodo foi construido para ler apenas um objeto salvo no arquivo;

> Como faço para devolver uma lista de objetos salvos no tal arquivo?

Por ultimo a famigerada classe Address:

```
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String street;
    String country;

    public Address() {
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return this.street;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuffer(" Street : ")
                .append(this.street).append(" Country : ")
                .append(this.country).toString();
    }

}
```

**ps:** estou usando o append como true, pois como sabemos quero acumular os objetos no arquivo.ser , e caso eu o omitisse, isso não seria possivel!
Caso exista outra forma de salvar os objetos no arquivos sem o uso do append , e seja possível listar esses arquivos, ficaria feliz em conhecer. 
Usei o Booleano append commo true , porque foi a unica alternativa que tive... não sabia como rescrever no arquivo sem apagar os objetos ja existentes previamente!

Comment: @AndréLuizdeGusmão Valeu cara vou dar um olhada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ler uma lista de objetos no arquivo tem de usar um laço/ciclo na parte da leitura e ir adicionando os objetos lidos a uma lista:

```
List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>(); //lista de Address

try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) {       

    while(true){
        addresses.add((Address) ois.readObject()); //le outro objeto e adicionar à lista
    }

} catch (EOFException ex){
    //fim da leitura aqui
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note que laço foi marcado como infinito e o fim da leitura foi capturado com `EOFException` o que pode parecer estranho. Na verdade o `null` é um valor válido de se obter lendo um objeto e por isso não é possível de testar o fim comparando com nulo mas apenas capturando exceções.

Podemos questionar a decisão do Java de implementar o fim do ficheiro por meio de exceções mas é como foi implementado para o [`ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) e [`readObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject()).

Deixo aqui a nota de que **escrevendo com `append` a `true` não irá conseguir desserializar múltiplos objetos**!

Posto isto mostro um exemplo de como utilizar esta lógica sem o `append` `true`, tentando-a deixar o mais parecida à que tinha:

```
public class WriteObject {

    //guarda a stream de saída aqui considerando N escritas seguidas pois não tem 
    //append e apenas no fim uma unica leitura para os objetos todos
    private ObjectOutputStream oos; 

    public void serializeAddressJDK7(Address address) {

        try {
            if (oos == null){ //se é o primeiro objeto a guardar inicia a stream
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("arquivo.ser"));
            }

            oos.writeObject(address);
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public List<Address> recuperarTodos(String filename) {

        try {
            oos.close(); //tenta fechar a stream de saída
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) {
            while (true) {
                addresses.add((Address) ois.readObject());
            }       
        } catch (EOFException ex) {
            // fim da leitura aqui
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return addresses;
    }

}
```

Testando agora no main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    obj.serializeAddressJDK7(address);
    obj.serializeAddressJDK7(address2);

    obj.recuperarTodos("arquivo.ser").stream().forEach(x-> System.out.println(x));
```

Saida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ele só consegue retornar a Lista quando o arquivo tem apenas um objeto! Aqui esta o erro :java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1381)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
 at wl.revisao.write2.WriteObject.recuperarTodos(WriteObject.java:58)
 at wl.revisao.write2.Main.main(Main.java:28)

Comment: @PenaPintada Assumo que o método `recuperarTodos` seja o que tem o código que eu aqui coloquei. Qual a sua assinatura ? E qual o caminho que está a ser passado/utilizado nesse método ?

Comment: Vou colocar ele no codigo acima

Comment: @PenaPintada O problema tem a ver com o `append` `true`, que basicamente não funciona com `writeObject` e `ReadObject`. Tem até uma pergunta relacionada no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473856/write-and-read-multiple-objects-to-file) com esse problema do `append`. E já consegui aqui testar sem o `append` e funciona mas é preciso dar outra lógica ao programa/classe `WriteObject`. Por isso estou mais tentado a remover a minha resposta do que alterar a lógica da que está na pergunta

Comment: Isso mesmo estou usando o append, obrigado pelo apoio.

Comment: @PenaPintada Com `append` não funciona para deserializar múltiplos objetos, dá para testar até de uma forma direta executando `obj.deserialzeAddressJDK7("arquivo.ser");` como estava no seu main 2 vezes seguidas, excluindo até todo o código que eu fiz, que aparece sempre o primeiro. E se testar dentro do método `deserialzeAddressJDK7` duas leituras seguidas com `address = (Address) ois.readObject();` tem o mesmo erro.

Comment: Obrigado ai cara! Grande resposta. Agora nasce outra questão  que vai ficar para a próxima! Espero contar com voce...

Comment: @PenaPintada De nada. Ficarei atento! Tudo de bom para si.